# How to use meteor-admin

Tags: javascript, meteor, adminlte

I am trying to use [meteor-admin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin). I installed everything and opened the link `localhost:PORT/admin`. After that I pasted this code in `root/client/admin.js` and `root/server/entry.js`:

```
AdminConfig = {
    adminEmails: [' ben@code2create.com'],
    collections:
    {
        Posts: {},
        Comments: {}
    }
}
```

I also tried creating a global file in `root/` for both client and server. Problem is that client file works but gives line : `You need to be an admin to view this page` on `localhost:PORT/admin` page. When I add the required code in `root/server`, I get this error:

```
=> Exited with code: 1
I20161013-19:43:24.308(5.5)? ** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
I20161013-19:43:24.308(5.5)? ** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
I20161013-19:43:24.309(5.5)? ** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
I20161013-19:43:24.309(5.5)? ** will still be sent to all clients.
I20161013-19:43:24.309(5.5)? **
I20161013-19:43:24.309(5.5)? ** Turn off autopublish by removing the autopublish package:
I20161013-19:43:24.309(5.5)? **
I20161013-19:43:24.309(5.5)? **   $ meteor remove autopublish
I20161013-19:43:24.310(5.5)? **
I20161013-19:43:24.310(5.5)? ** .. and make sure you have Meteor.publish() and Meteor.subscribe() calls
I20161013-19:43:24.310(5.5)? ** for each collection that you want clients to see.
I20161013-19:43:24.310(5.5)? 
W20161013-19:43:24.553(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/cortana/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.354htk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20161013-19:43:24.553(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20161013-19:43:24.554(5.5)? (STDERR)                       ^
W20161013-19:43:24.554(5.5)? (STDERR) 
W20161013-19:43:24.554(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: Posts is not in the [object global]
W20161013-19:43:24.554(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Assets.lookup (packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/utils.coffee:22:14)
W20161013-19:43:24.554(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Assets.adminCollectionObject (packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/utils.coffee:5:3)
W20161013-19:43:24.554(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/startup.coffee:63:16
W20161013-19:43:24.555(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20161013-19:43:24.555(5.5)? (STDERR)     at adminCreateTables (packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/startup.coffee:36:4)
W20161013-19:43:24.555(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/startup.coffee:166:2
W20161013-19:43:24.555(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/cortana/Desktop/deeplibrary/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:299:5
=> Exited with code: 1
I20161013-19:43:27.957(5.5)? ** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
I20161013-19:43:27.957(5.5)? ** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
I20161013-19:43:27.959(5.5)? ** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
I20161013-19:43:27.960(5.5)? ** will still be sent to all clients.
I20161013-19:43:27.960(5.5)? **
I20161013-19:43:27.960(5.5)? ** Turn off autopublish by removing the autopublish package:
I20161013-19:43:27.960(5.5)? **
I20161013-19:43:27.960(5.5)? **   $ meteor remove autopublish
I20161013-19:43:27.961(5.5)? **
I20161013-19:43:27.961(5.5)? ** .. and make sure you have Meteor.publish() and Meteor.subscribe() calls
I20161013-19:43:27.961(5.5)? ** for each collection that you want clients to see.
I20161013-19:43:27.961(5.5)? 
W20161013-19:43:28.246(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/cortana/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.354htk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20161013-19:43:28.246(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20161013-19:43:28.246(5.5)? (STDERR)                       ^
W20161013-19:43:28.246(5.5)? (STDERR) 
W20161013-19:43:28.247(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: Posts is not in the [object global]
W20161013-19:43:28.247(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Assets.lookup (packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/utils.coffee:22:14)
W20161013-19:43:28.247(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Assets.adminCollectionObject (packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/utils.coffee:5:3)
W20161013-19:43:28.247(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/startup.coffee:63:16
W20161013-19:43:28.247(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20161013-19:43:28.247(5.5)? (STDERR)     at adminCreateTables (packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/startup.coffee:36:4)
W20161013-19:43:28.247(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/yogiben_admin/lib/both/startup.coffee:166:2
W20161013-19:43:28.248(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/cortana/Desktop/deeplibrary/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:299:5
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

What should I do to remove this error? Why is this error here?
PS:

I also tried this code for `root/server` and got same errors:

```
AdminConfig = {
   roles: ['admin'],
   collections: {
     Posts: {}
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you have your own Posts Collection try something like

```
import { Posts } from '../imports/api/posts/posts.js'; // or wherever your Posts collection is defined
AdminConfig = {
   roles: ['admin'],
   collections: {
     Posts: { collectionObject: Posts} // tell about collectionObject
   }
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the autopublish package from your app.

```
meteor remove autopublish
```

You need to also defined your Posts collection to solve the another issue.

> Error: Posts is not in the

Comment: That doesnt work. I removed the autopublish module but now the app doesnt launch. It just gets stuck on `starting your app`.

Comment: Your answer does not work . I removed autopublish and run repeated same error